# how to change direction of TOC in aspose.word for C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words, tableofcontents

I create a table of content by Aspose.Word but my document direction is right to left and i want to change direction to rtl.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following code example to create the table of content in right to left direction. Hope this helps you.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

// Create a document builder to insert content with into document.
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Specify the locale so Microsoft Word recognizes this text as Arabic - Saudi Arabia.

builder.Font.LocaleIdBi = 1025;
builder.ParagraphFormat.Bidi = true;
builder.Font.NameBi = "Heading 1";
builder.Font.SizeBi = 10;
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
builder.Font.Bidi = true;

doc.Styles[StyleIdentifier.Toc1].ParagraphFormat.Bidi = true;
doc.Styles[StyleIdentifier.Toc1].Font.Bidi = true;

builder.InsertTableOfContents("\\o \"1-3\" \\h \\z \\u");
builder.Writeln();

builder.ParagraphFormat.StyleIdentifier = StyleIdentifier.Heading1;
builder.Writeln("مرحبا هناك ما هو اسمك وماذا تفعل في هذا");

// Call the method below to update the TOC.
doc.UpdateFields();
doc.Save(MyDir + "output.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.